# Term for "representative" animal sound?

Tags: terminology, animals

Is there a term for the sound word associated with a certain type of animal, that is considered the most frequent or usual representation?
e.g. Cat - meow; Duck - quack; Owl - whoo; Frog - ribbit; etc.

Generally, I guess these are all animal onomatopoeias. But wondering if there might be something more exact.

Comment: *animal onomatopoeia* seems to me to be perfectly exact. Is there a reason you think it's not?

Answer (score 3):

The word you want is **cry**.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cry#Noun),

> Noun
>   Cry (plural cries)
>    6. (transitive, intransitive, of an animal) A typical sound made by the species in question.
>   *"Woof" is the cry of a dog, while "neigh" is the cry of a horse.*

More support from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cry), [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cry) and [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cry).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the term is simply [*animal sounds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_sounds). The study of animal sounds and their effects on living organisms is called [*bioacoustics*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bioacoustics).