# Verb for when cats meow other than meow itself

Tags: verbs, sounds, onomatopoeia, animals

If

- a dog barks "woof" (or some other variation)
- a frog croaks "ribbit"

is there a verb for when cats "meow" other than "meow" itself?

I am specifically looking for a word that is usually only associated with a cat's "meow" similar to how bark is usually only associated with a dog's "woof", so cry as suggested in ["Term for “representative” animal sound?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301040/term-for-representative-animal-sound) won't work.

Comment: (As an aside not really related to the question, most frogs _don’t_ croak ‘ribbit’—they make an impressively varied range of noise, of which only a small number are even close to the characteristic sound we think of as a ribbit.)

Comment: Cats are *supposed* to meow or purr only. All the same, the representations of their sound is always called onomatopoeia.

Comment: The only possible expression seems to be "the animal made a sound" or even, "said."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet As a continuation of your aside, the OED shocked me by discussing how the word 'ribbit' itself only dates to the '60s, when it was popularized on American television by cartoons featuring Mel Blanc & co.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *mew* (it's kind of cheating, I know, but ODO lists it as a *verb* first, as opposed to the entries listing [miaow/meow](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/miaow) as a *noun* first).

> **mew** *verb*
>   (of a cat or gull) make a characteristic high-pitched crying noise.
>   ‘Her cat mewed at her anxiously and snarled at Cameron, who snarled right back.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mew)

Depending on the cat's temper at the time, *snarl* from the second example above might work instead; or perhaps [*purr*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/purr). Big cats such as lions *roar*, but that sound is nothing like a *meow*.

Comment: Even I got the question wrong it seems. A verb for when cats make a sound other than "meow" itself.

Comment: @Kris Then this answer scrapes by on a technicality. :)

Comment: See my new comment. What do you think?

Comment: @Kris It looks like the comment I responded to. The bit about *cheating* was that it's spelt differently from the OP's 4-letter cat call even though the difference in pronunciation is hardly on the scale of croak/ribbit or bark/woof.

Comment: @Kris Shall I delete this answer? :)

Comment: No. Let's keep that for its own contribution. I'm just trying to say that we seem to have got the Q wrong.

Comment: You really should delete it if you're just using it as a synonym for "meow". What should make it stay is editing it to address that mewing isn't what full-grown cats do at full volume but what kittens or querulous cats do.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It's a different word and even pronounced differently. This seems correct to me.

Comment: @lly What's it got to do with querulousness or kittens, the dictionary gives the word as a variant of meow along with miaou, miaow and miaul. www.thefreedictionary.com/mew

Comment: @Lawrence: I think this is the only possible answer. Even if it's not completely satisfactory, don't delete it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, everyone. I'll leave this answer up.

Answer (score 1):

This answers your question only partially.

*Cats **howl** at night during the mating season.*

There are other types of *mating calls* or *mating **cries*** apart from **howling** and **meowing**, including **trilling**, **cooing** and **mewing**. Still other *vocalisations* are **yowling**, **moaning** and **wailing**.

Source: [Melody in Human-Cat Communication project](http://vr.humlab.lu.se/projects/meowsic/catvoc.html) at Lund University (Yes, there is indeed such a thing!)

Comment: I think the thing to underline re: your source's claims is that these are all considered by them to be *separate and distinguishable* vocalizations, not synonyms that they would use interchangeably with one another.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

> If
>
> - a dog barks "woof" (or some other variation)
> - a frog croaks "ribbit"
>
> is there a verb for when cats "meow" other than "meow" itself?
>
> I am specifically looking for a word that is usually only associated with a cat's "meow" similar to how bark is usually only associated with a dog's "woof", so cry... won't work.

**First off**, dogs don't bark "woof". They bark "bark". They're two different sounds. Ditto yelps, arfs, bows-wow, grunts, howls, whimpers, and cries. Ditto croaks and ribbits, although note that "ribbit" is [apparently American frog slang rather than a formal register](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/241749).

**Second**, it's just a second onomatopoeia that you're using in a verb sense to describe a second different onomatopoeia in a noun sense. Bark isn't a verb employed with the noun woof. They're *both* nouns ([1](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230108), [2](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/15569)) and both can be used as a verb ([1](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230107), [2](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/15570)) meaning "to make the sound ~". Same thing with "bow-wow" ([1](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/22292), [2](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/22293)). Same thing with "yelp" ([1](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/231563), [2](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/231564)). Same thing with cat noises.

**Similarly**, you could as easily have a cat "[mew](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/117754)([l](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/117769)) '[meow](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/117819)' " or "[purr](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/155024) '[mew](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/117755)(l)' " or "[meow](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/233675) '[purr](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/155020)' ". They could ["hiss"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87264) any of them. But all of those words [should more properly describe different sounds](http://vr.humlab.lu.se/projects/meowsic/catvoc.html).

That said, **third**, there are the verbs "[**waul**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226382)" and "[**caterwaul**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28909)" which means to wail (i.e., meow) like a cat in heat. The OED also particularly associates "[**yawl**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/231295)" and "[**yowl**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/232204)" with cats, albeit in the same limited sense: the pained meowing of a female cat in estrus.